# iOS Facebook SDK: Blank screen after you already authorized app?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

I added a 'Login with Facebook' button, but running it in the emulator is not working after the first time. Here's what happens when I click the 'Login with Facebook' button: [pic](http://s1.postimg.org/5cbpr6xvz/Screen_Shot_2015_10_26_at_11_30_19_PM.png)

Once I click OK I get: [pic](http://s1.postimg.org/rmuzdf5sf/Screen_Shot_2015_10_26_at_11_30_29_PM.png)
If I click 'Done', it says the request was cancelled

Comment: reset simulator once. Otherwise go to safari and logout Facebook there.

Answer (score 0):

In the second pic its loading and getting response from Facebook.com server. . .The best approach is to run it on device and than test it.some times emulator didn't work properly.Thanks

Comment: What if the same problem persists on the device?